# Return time to end of next day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns: Start_Date and End_Date.

The task is to return a time to end of next day (using T-SQL, SSMS 14.0).

For example:

```
Start_Date = '2018-11-21 23:40:00'          End_Date = '2018-11-23 02:40:00'
```

The query should return 3 rows:

```
0 hour 20 min -- time between 2018-11-21 23:40:00 and 2018-11-22 00:00:00
24 hour 0 min -- time between 2018-11-22 00:00:00 and 2018-11-23 00:00:00
2 hour 40 min -- time between 2018-11-23 00:00:00 and 2018-11-23 02:40:00
```

I suppose it can be implemented using the cursor or recursive CTE.

Comment: The task is not hard but probably you need to explain more like what is the logic? and why it can't be done?

Comment: @ViKiNG Because I have no idea how to remove time (set 00:00:00 if to say correctly) for next days

Comment: You mean 3 columns? or 3 rows?

Comment: @Sami I mean 3 rows

Comment: you can use like select `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((to_char(startdate+rownum),'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00'))-(start_date),'HH:MM')`as first_date from table where rownum <=3. Can you please check if this is working

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Did you see Oracle tag there?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried, and why its not working?

Comment: you can use like `select FORMAT(FORMAT((startdate+declared_value),'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00')-(start_date),'HH:MM') from table ` Can you please check if this is working >Actually we will need a value set to be 1 and well add on startdate like here ive added rownum well add that declared value and end the loop when value reaches 3.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja From where did you get _rownum_?

Comment: @Sami just check what i have edited if you could please not point on the syntax as such i am just giving a sample query to begin with. Did I post it as an answer and if my solution approach is wrong could you please share your advice and suggestion to resolve.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja It's not about syntax you give a column which is not exists at all, and I ask from where did you get it

Comment: I have edited now please check and about rownum my bad i included it as a standard name which i din mean it was just one declared value set to 1 and then adding it to formated startdate and incrementing in the form of  loop of 3 cycles.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Simply, that won't return 3 rows as OP wanted, and it won't work anyway.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja what is `declared_value` now?  Also, `FORMAT` wasn't supported until SQL Server 2012, I think - and we don't know his version... The primary question here, is how to turn 1 row into multiple rows; formatting the output is only a minor detail.  I think the point is, despite your best efforts, you're not really helping until you have the full picture.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a "time interval" data type. (It has TIME but that can't handle 24 hours) Just use seconds, or milliseconds, and handle conversion to a friendlier format for humans in your application. It will make all the code much more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `CTE` can be used with contribution of `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` functions together as :

```
CREATE VIEW DAYS AS
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 1 as nr
  UNION ALL
  SELECT nr+1
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE nr <= DATEDIFF( day, CONVERT(date, '2018-11-21 23:40:00'),
                             CONVERT(date, '2018-11-23 02:40:00') )
)
SELECT 
   DATEDIFF(
             minute, 
             (case when nr > 1 then 
                   DATEADD ( day , nr - 1 , CONVERT(date, '2018-11-21 23:40:00') )
              else
                   DATEADD ( day , nr - 1 , CONVERT(datetime, '2018-11-21 23:40:00'))
              end),

             (case when nr < 3 then 
                   DATEADD ( day , nr , CONVERT(date, '2018-11-21 23:40:00') )
              else
                   DATEADD ( day , nr - 3, CONVERT(datetime, '2018-11-23 02:40:00'))
              end)
               ) as time_diff                         
  FROM CTE;

SELECT cast(time_diff/60 as varchar) + ' hours '
     + cast(time_diff % 60 as varchar) + ' minutes' as "Time Difference" FROM DAYS;

Time Difference
-------------------
 0 hours 20 minutes
24 hours  0 minutes
 2 hours 40 minutes
```

[***dbfiddle demo***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b39574ca3165a750695c03088ef4bd1)

Comment: From OP question last row should return _"2 hour 40 min -- time between 2018-11-23 00:00:00 and 2018-11-23 02:40:00"_

Comment: Yeah, it happen, but still we have the edit button there ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired results as

```
WITH Dates AS
(
  SELECT 1 RN,

         @sd StartD,
         CAST(DATEADD(Day, -1, @ed) AS DATE) EndD
  UNION
  SELECT 2,
         CAST(DATEADD(Day, 1, @sd) AS DATE),
         CAST(@ed AS DATE)
  UNION 
  SELECT 3,
         CAST(@ed AS DATE),
         @ed
)
SELECT 
 CAST( DATEDIFF(YEAR, StartD, EndD) AS VARCHAR(10) )+ ' Years, '+
 CAST( DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartD, EndD)%12 AS VARCHAR(10) )+ ' Months, '+
 CAST( (DATEDIFF(DAY, StartD, EndD)%31)%12 
 - CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN RN ELSE 0 END AS VARCHAR(10) )+ ' Days, '+
 CAST( (DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartD, EndD)%60)%24 
 - CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN RN ELSE 0 END AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' Hours,'+
 CAST( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartD, EndD)%60 AS VARCHAR(10) ) +' Minutes, '+
 CAST( DATEDIFF(SECOND, StartD, EndD)%60 AS VARCHAR(10) ) +' Seconds' AS Results
FROM Dates;
```

**Results:**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                         Results                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 0 Years, 0 Months, 0 Days, 0 Hours,20 Minutes, 0 Seconds |
| 0 Years, 0 Months, 1 Days, 0 Hours,0 Minutes, 0 Seconds  |
| 0 Years, 0 Months, 0 Days, 2 Hours,40 Minutes, 0 Seconds |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=938119a344f46c2d940a9df11eb96f7e)**

Finally, as a note I think your results should be

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                         Results                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 0 Years, 0 Months, 1 Days, 1 Hours,20 Minutes, 0 Seconds |
| 0 Years, 0 Months, 1 Days, 0 Hours,0 Minutes, 0 Seconds  |
| 0 Years, 0 Months, 0 Days, 2 Hours,40 Minutes, 0 Seconds |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

if I'm right, then all what you need to do is removing the two (2) `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will want the ability to apply this to a variety of task durations. Here I have used a dynamic "tally table" which just a series of numbers from 0 to (in this case) 100, if you need a greater range amend the `Tally` cte by adding extra cross joins. If you already have a table of numbers, or your own preferred method for this substitute that for mine.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ID Integer NOT NULL
  ,Start_Date datetime NOT NULL
  ,End_Date   datetime NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,Start_Date,End_Date) VALUES (1,'2018-11-21 23:40:00','2018-11-23 02:40:00');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,Start_Date,End_Date) VALUES (2,'2018-11-23 13:40:00','2018-11-23 22:40:00');
INSERT INTO mytable(id,Start_Date,End_Date) VALUES (3,'2018-11-18 23:40:00','2018-11-23 02:40:00');
```

3 test cases, as given, + a very short duration + a longer duration:

```
;WITH
Digits AS (
          SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL
          SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL  
          SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
          SELECT 9
          )
, Tally AS (
          SELECT  [ones].digit
                + [tens].digit * 10
                -- + [hundreds].digit * 100
                AS number
          FROM Digits [ones]
          CROSS JOIN Digits [tens]
          -- CROSS JOIN Digits [hundreds]
          )
select 
     ID
    , cast(ca2.minutes/60 as varchar) + ' hours '
      + cast(ca2.minutes % 60 as varchar) + ' minutes' as Duration
    , format(on_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') on_date
    , portion
    , format(start_date,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm') start_date
    , format(end_date,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm') end_date
from mytable t
inner join Tally on Tally.number <= datediff(dd,t.Start_Date,t.End_Date)
cross apply (
    select dateadd(dd,tally.number,dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,t.start_date),0))  on_date
    ) ca
cross apply (
    select
      case
           when t.start_date >= ca.on_date and t.end_date <= dateadd(dd,1,ca.on_date) then datediff(minute,t.start_date,t.end_date)
           when cast(t.end_date as date) = ca.on_date then datediff(minute,ca.on_date,t.end_date)
           when ca.on_date between t.start_date and t.end_date then 24*60
           when ca.on_date < t.start_date then datediff(minute,t.start_date,dateadd(dd,1,ca.on_date))
      end minutes
    , case
           when t.start_date >= ca.on_date and t.end_date <= dateadd(dd,1,ca.on_date) then 'is on'
           when cast(t.end_date as date) = ca.on_date then 'end'
           when ca.on_date between t.start_date and t.end_date then 'span' 
           when ca.on_date < t.start_date then 'start'
      end portion
    ) ca2
```

I have used 2 apply operators, the first turns a number from the `Tally` into a date, and this is then re-used by the alias `on_date` in the second apply where we can calculate the duration. Note the second case expression `portion` is not essential, it's just there to help document the logic.

Result:

```
       ID        Duration         on_date     portion      start_date          end_date      
 ---- ---- -------------------- ------------ --------- ------------------ ------------------ 
   1    1   0 hours 20 minutes   2018-11-21   start     2018-11-21 11:40   2018-11-23 02:40  
   2    1   24 hours 0 minutes   2018-11-22   span      2018-11-21 11:40   2018-11-23 02:40  
   3    1   2 hours 40 minutes   2018-11-23   end       2018-11-21 11:40   2018-11-23 02:40  
   4    2   9 hours 0 minutes    2018-11-23   is on     2018-11-23 01:40   2018-11-23 10:40  
   5    3   0 hours 20 minutes   2018-11-18   start     2018-11-18 11:40   2018-11-23 02:40  
   6    3   24 hours 0 minutes   2018-11-19   span      2018-11-18 11:40   2018-11-23 02:40  
   7    3   24 hours 0 minutes   2018-11-20   span      2018-11-18 11:40   2018-11-23 02:40  
   8    3   24 hours 0 minutes   2018-11-21   span      2018-11-18 11:40   2018-11-23 02:40  
   9    3   24 hours 0 minutes   2018-11-22   span      2018-11-18 11:40   2018-11-23 02:40  
  10    3   2 hours 40 minutes   2018-11-23   end       2018-11-18 11:40   2018-11-23 02:40
```

also see: https://rextester.com/VPTI85082